# Hosts available via IE only

Tags: windows-server-2008, proxy, hosts

Here's a situation I haven't seen before: I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine that can see other hosts *only* from Internet Explorer.

I can't ping them, can't find them via tracert, etc. All other modes result in an error like "Remote name could not be resolved". The exact error varies by tool, but they all center around being unable to resolve the host, either by name or IPv4 address (I haven't tried v6). Oddly I can reach hosts if I initiate the session from IE.

I have tried disabling the firewall, using "netsh firewall set opmode disable", but no dice. I've also tried flushing my DNS cache. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
nslookup also fails:

```
> nslookup w3.org  
***myDnsName can't find w3.org: Non-existent domain
```

Here's the result of ipconfig /all, with names changed to protect the innocent:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : ServerName
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : MyHostName
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : MyHostName
   System Quarantine State . . . . . : Not Restricted


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : MyHostName
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82566DM Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0F-FE-54-63-3C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : AnIPv6Address(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : AnIPv6Address(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : AnIPv4Address(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, September 21, 2009 12:13:26 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, October 09, 2009 4:51:54 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : AnIPv6Address
                                       AnIPv4Address
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : AnIPv4Address
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : AnIPv4Address
                                       AnIPv4Address
                                       AnIPv4Address
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : AnIPv4Address
   Secondary WINS Server . . . . . . : AnIPv4Address
                                       AnIPv4Address
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.MyHostName:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : MyHostName
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : AnIPv6Address(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : AnIPv6Address(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : AnIPv6Address
                                       AnIPv6Address
                                       AnIPv6Address
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : AnIPv4Address
                                       AnIPv4Address8
                                       AnIPv4Address
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the machine doesn't have name resolution and/or routing, but IE is using a proxy, which allows it (and only it) to access web sites.

Have a look at the proxy settings.

Comment: Thank you, this was a problem with the upstream proxy (ISA) configuration. I really appreciate the insight!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like a firewall (either the built-in Windows one, or an external device) is blocking everything except port 80.

You can test his by trying to TELNET to port 80 of a different machine, then trying port 23 (of course, ensure you enable TELNET on the target machine for this test)

Also, please paste the results of an NSLOOKUP (specifically, the first 2 lines - SERVER and ADDRESS)

Comment: I disagree. Without name resolution, IE wouldn't be able to connect to anything.

Comment: Hmmmm - makes sense, althou8gh he never mentioned trying to directly do an nslookup

Comment: Good point. nslookup also fails. Added a note in the body.

Comment: In that case it sounds like Massimo was on the right track - can you add the results of a IPCONFIG /ALL to your question please?

Answer (score 0):

Is the server joined to a domain?

Are the other hosts on the same subnet?

Do you have a WINS server configured?

Comment: Yes, the server is joined to a domain. 
There are other hosts on the subnet. 
WINS is not enabled.